# Is it possible to receive a message from the client on Aerogear?

Tags: aerogear

I am trying out a project on OpenShift using Aerogear UPS. I am able to push messages to the clients, but is there a way to get messages from the client?

Aerogear seems to be the only packaged XMPP solution on OpenShift, and it appears to be one way messaging platform. Please tell me it ain't so.

Answer (score 2):

It ain't so. *

- Well it kind of is so but not for long!  In UPS 1.1.0 we are planning on introducing support for metrics support.  Right now it is just a glorified read receipt with a phenomenally sexy dashboard.  In UPS 1.2.0 we are moving the metrics from HTTP to XMPP messaging (for Android).  Please comment on our JIRAs (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AGDROID-433) or bug us on the aerogear mailing lists (https://aerogear.org/community/#contact).

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I think the Jira is more about supporting new GCM features (topic subscription, instance IDs etc.), rather than bi-directional communication. Unless I misread the contents of Jira?

Comment: So right now we send some basic metrics using http.  This will migrate to using XMPP to send the metrics which is the beginnings of bidirectional support.  

But mention in the XMPP task or file a jira yourself.  We do take the community seriously.